# volttron BACnet scan with virtual box ubuntu

Tags: volttron

I am running ubuntu 18.04 LTS on virtual box. Is it possible to scan for real (non virtual) BACnet devices on a LAN through the virtual box VM?

How would I set the BACpypes.ini?

My Windows 10 machine if I do a `ipconfig/all` this doesn't work with the BACpypes.ini when run `bacnet_scan.py` on my VM
[image]

Or this IP address of my Windows 10 machine.
[image]

Both IP addresses implemented onto the BACpypes.ini will throw an:
`OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address`

If I do an `ifconfig` of my ubuntu VM this doesnt appear to error anything on the `bacnet_scan.py` but none of my BACnet devices come up either. Any tips greatly appreciated...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your VM is set up with a host-only connection.  Host-only connection does what it says on the tin: you're only able to communicate with the host.  To contact with the LAN around the host, set the VM's networking mode to "NAT" (This makes your VM routable through the host machine).  Then, look up your VM's IP again and try that.